# Hyperlink colour changes when click is held

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have some hyperlinked text.
However, if I click it (but don't let go of the mouse or pull the mouse away) it disappears. Almost as if there is something other than `a:link` & `a:visited` that needs to be styled and the text is turning white (I have a white background).

Does anybody know which tag I need to style to change the colour of the state of the class when the mouse is held on the link? I've tried every `<a>` tag I can find and nothing is preventing the change of colour. I'm baffled as I've never come across this before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `:focus`?

Comment: Can you demonstrate the issue in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: That should be `a:active`. [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/3BsNN/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope it helps

```
a:active{
    color:#000000 !important;   /*or set the color of your choice*/
}
```

Comment: I tried this about 5 times to no avail, saw your comment, tried it again and it magically decided to work. Dunno if it had something to do with the caching system in place on what I'm working on as it sometimes messes up like that. Thanks!

Comment: bielive me sir it happens ALL THE TIME lool , good to know i could help :)

Comment: btw you were adding the !important keyword ? if not it might be that some other css was overiding what you were adding

Comment: I actually tried both with & without the !important keyword and still no change. I even tried ctrl+f5 refreshing & inspecting the element which claimed the a:active tag was there and functioning. Strange, strange, CSS... :D

Comment: maybe you were right it had something to do with tha caching system

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hope this will help you.

```
.a:hover,.a:active {
color:black;
}
```